# How to clear correcly for this design?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a website that uses float/clear method for having a 3 columns design (2 asides -left and right- and the main article).

Both aside are floated (one left and the other one right), but I have to include a form automatically generated inside my article that has some clear:both included.
This results in the form appearing below the asides because of the clear.

Did I miss something? What can I do in this situation? It has been a while since I made a website, and I am stuck here.

Here is a minimalist code of my problem:

jsfiddle.net/89kpd/

I want the form content to be just below the "My Form" title.

What I could think of was to use display:inline-block inside the form instead:

jsfiddle.net/89kpd/2/

But it would require me to change the inner component, which I would prefer not to.

But maybe there's a better way to design my site at the beginning, without using the float/clear method. I suppose it's here that I should make something.
I don't care about IE6 compatibility. For IE7, we'll see, but probably not important...

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/89kpd/3/

Comment: @j08691 Thank you it works... it was simple, I should have thought about it... I will probably need something to correctly manage the #main width, as it should take all the available space left. I'll look into it. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, I'll add the link with a brief explanation in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try floating the #main div to the left so that it float up between your other floated divs.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/89kpd/3/)**

Add:

```
#main {
 float:left;   
}​
```

to your CSS

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have plenty of things to do. The problem with this solution is that my #main div doesn't take all the available space anymore. I want the whole design to be at least 1000px large, but take the whole page if more than 1000px is available.
But, by floating the #main, I don't have that support anymore. An idea?

Comment: Thank you that works well. I had to make some JavaScript to set a min-height to #main that is at least equal to the smaller aside, so that my footer doesn't overlap with the asides, but it's good now.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the entire thing needs to be 500px wide. Try this HTML:

```
<div id="blue">
    <aside id="black"></aside>
    <article id="main">
        <h2 class="center">My Form:</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
    </article>
    <aside id="red"></aside>
    <br clear="all" />
</div>
<br clear="all" />
```

CSS:

```
#blue{background:blue; width: 500px; height: 600px; color:white;}

#black{float:left; background:black; width: 120px; height: 345px; float: left;}

#red{float:left; background:red; width: 120px; height: 345px; float:right;}

#main{float:left;width:260px;}

label { float:left; width:100px; }

input { float:left; width: 150px; color:black; }

.row { clear: both; }

h2 { font-size:20px; text-align:center; }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have plenty of things to do. The problem with this solution is that my #main div doesn't take all the available space anymore. I want the whole design to be at least 1000px large, but take the whole page if more than 1000px is available. But, by floating the #main, I don't have that support anymore. An idea?